# Cypress custom find command is not chainable

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, testing, cypress

I want to create a custom Cypress `find` command like so to utilize a `data-test` attribute.

**cypress/support/index.ts**

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to get a DOM element by data-test attribute.
       * @example cy.getByTestId('element')
       */
       getByTestId(selector: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;

      /**
       * Custom command to find a DOM element by data-test attribute.
       * @example cy.findByTestId('element')
       */
      findByTestId(selector: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
    }
  }
}
```

**cypress/support/commands.ts**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getByTestId', (selector, ...args) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-test=${selector}]`, ...args);
});

Cypress.Commands.add(
  'findByTestId',
  { prevSubject: 'element' },
  (subject, selector) => {
    return subject.find(`[data-test=${selector}]`);
  }
);
```

Here `subject` is of type `JQuery<HTMLElement>` and not `Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>`, so `subject.find` is not chainable with others methods.

I get the following errors from Typescript.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(name: "findByTestId", options: CommandOptions & { prevSubject: false; }, fn: CommandFn<"findByTestId">): void', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(name: "findByTestId", options: CommandOptions & { prevSubject: true | keyof PrevSubjectMap<unknown> | ["optional"]; }, fn: CommandFnWithSubject<"findByTestId", unknown>): void', gave the following error.
  Overload 3 of 4, '(name: "findByTestId", options: CommandOptions & { prevSubject: "element"[]; }, fn: CommandFnWithSubject<"findByTestId", JQuery<HTMLElement>>): void', gave the following error.ts(2769)
cypress.d.ts(22, 5): The expected type comes from property 'prevSubject' which is declared here on type 'CommandOptions & { prevSubject: false; }'
```

**Desired usage**

```
cy.getByTestId('some-element')
  .findByTestId('some-test-id')
  .should('have.text', 'Text');
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: It may be beneficial to merge the two commands and make the end result a dual command. Maybe even add  `contains text` functionality to search with data-test and text.

Comment: Sometimes I would have several calls to `findByTestId` chained together so a dual command wouldn't work in this case, but great suggestion!

Comment: A [dual command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Dual-Commands) can be either a parent or child command depending on whether a subject was passed to the command.

Comment: Oh, I understand, would you mind writing a small code snippet to show how this dual command could be used ?

Comment: Just a small sample `subject ? cy.wrap(subject).find('[data-test=${selector}]' :  cy.get('[data-test=${selector}]', ...args)`. If a `subject` is passed, then you can wrap it and use `.find()` within that element.

Comment: Awesome! How would you replace a line like `cy.getByTestId('first-id').findByTestId('id-inside-first-element').findByTestId('id-within-this-second-element')` with this new command? That's the use case I was thinking about

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer to detail this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `commands` file would have a command like this. Note that this will log the cy.wraps and you may want to pass `log: false` to suppress that if you choose. You can also add another agrument and have an `if` block for text to use `data-testid` with `.contains()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'byTestId',
  { prevSubject: 'optional' },
  (subject, id) => {
    if (subject) {
      return cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-testid="${id}"]`)
    }
    return cy.get(`[data-testid="${id}"]`)
  },
)
```

This would be an application of the command.

```
cy.byTestId('first-id')
  // maybe some assertions here for visibility check
  .byTestId('id-inside-first-element')
  // maybe some assertions here for visibility check
  .byTestId('id-within-this-second-element')
```

Comment: The command is good as-is, but just for interest sake - you can do it in one line `return cy.get(subject || 'body').find(``[data-testid="${id}"]``)` since `cy.get()` is implicitly doing a find within `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, I'll clean up my code right now!

Answer (score 9):

I may be off the mark, but `subject.find(...)` is using jQuery find.

Perhaps you want `cy.wrap(subject).find(...)` which should yield the Cypress.Chainable wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Had to add a `cy.wrap` command around the JQuery element like so.

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'findByTestId',
  { prevSubject: 'element' },
  (subject, selector) => {
    return cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-test=${selector}]`);
  }
)
```